# Jquery EasyUI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

Here is the function part , I put it in the main page, which is the page has accordation, it does not work unfortunately.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.easyui-accordion').css('height', '240px') <====this is 

function addTab(title, url){  
    if ($('#tt').tabs('exists', title)){  
        $('#tt').tabs('select', title);  
    } else {  
        var content = '<iframe scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"  src="'+url+'" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>';  
        $('#tt').tabs('add',{  
            title:title,  
            content:content,  
            closable:true  
        });  
    }  
}  

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#closeMe").click(function() {
        $(this)
            .parent()
            .slideUp();
    });
});

</script>
</head>
```

Part 2 and optional: Also, i have some other page also can not call the jquery function properly, would you mind have a look at it?
This is for calling a popup box using jquery.

```
<script>

$(function() { $("#openDialog").on('click', loadDialogBox); });

function loadDialogBox() {'
    $("#myEmptyDiv").load("popup.php", function() {

      $("#myEmptyDiv").dialog({
         title: "Permission Setting",
         autoOpen: false,
         buttons: { "Submit" : submitDialogForm() }
      });
      $("#myEmptyDiv").dialog("open");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addlist").validate();
});
</script>
```

This is the link which suppose to generate a popup box of popup.php..

```
<a id="openDialog" href="#"> Permission Settings</a>
```

That is the last thing , Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: have seen jQuery's main lib extension, [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)? It includes both an accordion and a dialog that are way easier to use and manipulate than what you are trying to do here

Comment: scratch that, i just noticed you using .dialog so maybe you have but if i had time to fully rewrite this for you i would, but i dont, but i can tell you, you really appear to be "reinventing the wheel" with some of this stuff.  Maybe you should take a breather and review your kode from the start and ask yourself "What is the 'easiest' way to achieve this without alot of code?"  What i mean is, alot of these "extra funcs" you're writing by hand and adding and using later, you could easily be setting on the jQuery calls themselves and then define the css as needed.

Comment: is it refer to the part 2 ?
i did this since i don;t know how to use a jquery easyui to  pop up  a  new page content using dialog , in their example , they just have a popup with element in <div> ...</div> ,Thank you

Comment: using the function in jquery easyui is much easier  though

Comment: oic, your using easyui, not really too familiar with it as i opted out of using it long ago when i found jqueryui.  I'll admit, it's missing some of the features that easyui has, however, the reason i opted for jui instead is simple, through use and expirmentation jqueryui became the easiest of the two to use, and some of those extra features that it doesn have, are a.) easy to incorporate via plugin or manually and/or b.) coming soon if you have a look at their [wiki](http://wiki.jqueryui.com) sight which also includes a vast array of plugins for jqueryui from (mostly) pro jQuery coders.

Comment: However, keep in mind with every jQueryUI update, they add in the plugins that seem to be fully functional and almost bug free (a few slip through sometimes, but not often, most "bugs" i've found arn't bugs as much as they are misuse of the lib at hand)

Comment: sure i can use two plugin at the same time as well .Besides,  can you notice the syntax problem in my code? i think there should be some missing bucket or colun so that the function can not call. but i can not figure it out.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text isn't displayed properly because the accordion uses a fixed height, and it then calculates the `panel-body` and the `header` heights. So when you expand a panel, the text will not be displayed anymore (or partially) because it uses up all space.

A simple workaround for this is to add some height after pageload to the `easyui-accordion` container to compensate for your text.

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hFsxP/15/)

Comment: sorry, do you mean adding $('.easyui-accordion').css('height', '240px'); to my page? Where should it locate?

Comment: I have edited my post and i put it  above the "function addTab(title, url){  " Please have a look . Thank you.

Comment: no, it has to be executed after page load, so put it inside the `$(document).ready(...)` function. After you add the  `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to add the text inside the `<div id="aa">` ? you can add it outside the div , and everything will be just fine , check here http://jsfiddle.net/hFsxP/1/

Comment: then it would not slide up and down just like "Read our documentation" at jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes it'll be outside the accordion .